# I've only gotten 130 reputation today, but I'm not getting full rep for upvotes

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation

I have two upvotes on my answer on question:
[How to test eCommerce software for credit cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489474/how-to-test-ecommerce-software-for-credit-cards/1489666#1489666)

But I got 5 points for them.

I am not complaining about the points. I am curious how I got five points (it was initially 5 for the first upvote, zero for the second).

I have 130 rep points for today so I am not near the cap.

It isn't a community wiki question, but regardless, I didn't think it was possible to get 5 points.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you're at 190 (you need to click "today") - so I'm guessing you did actually hit the rep cap, and have also had a vote retracted?

Comment: Oh, thank you, I would just click on the envelope and I thought that would tell me today's info.

Comment: It does... for some as-yet-undefined meaning of "today" ;-p This is a constant FAQ. I still have no clue what the time frame is that you get by default!

Comment: I think there should be a little 'Go home! You have reached rep cap today' so that people will see this :)

Comment: @abyx - That's not the intended purpose of Rep. Hence no show. The daily Rep cap is intending to incorporate time spent on the site as a part of the score. There's no way a guy that's been here earns everyone's respect in one day. Even though he may get everyone's attention, people will quickly forget about him if he goes AWOL after that. Which begs the question, should Rep deteriorate after so much time of activity, or should people always lose a little rep everyday? Maybe once they reach a certain level, yes?

Comment: @Marc Please, what is the rep cap? I got only 50 points today, and this is happening to me.Thanks

Comment: @DrBeco - probably at least one is community wiki

Comment: @Marc Thanks, but I don't see any wiki there. Sorry to bring you to this case. [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535319/what-can-create-a-lexical-error-in-c) and its [Meta Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85898/what-happened-with-the-question-about-example-of-a-lexical-error) when it was mistakingly deleted. Could you take a look, please?

Comment: @DrBeko - do you mean the 7 votes on a **question**? question votes are +5-1, not +10-2

Answer (score 0):

When this happens in the future (vote reversals after the cap) will now appropriately adjust for the reputation cap (underneath, think of it as a per-day rep recalc that happens on the fly).  There may be a delay up up to 5 minutes, but your reputation will be correctly adjusted after that.