# Why do upvotes not always result in +10?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How did I get 5 points for 2 upvotes on my answer, on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23787/how-did-i-get-5-points-for-2-upvotes-on-my-answer-on-so)
>   [No reputation for upvote given?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28402/no-reputation-for-upvote-given)
>   [“Recent activity” vote counts are missing/corrupt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29716/recent-activity-vote-counts-are-missing-corrupt)

Why does this happen?

[image: screenshot of rep history]

In this case, I have 3 upvotes on one question and 7 upvotes on another. But the net is just 22, instead of 100. Why? Neither are community wiki.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23787/how-did-i-get-5-points-for-2-upvotes-on-my-answer-on-so

Comment: Also, for the complete answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a cap on the increase in reputation for one day.

See [How did I get 5 points for 2 upvotes on my answer, on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23787/how-did-i-get-5-points-for-2-upvotes-on-my-answer-on-so)