# What happened with the question about example of a lexical error?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, bug

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535319/an-example-of-a-lexical-error-in-c) (of mine) is giving *page not found* error.

It was a really useful question about lexical errors, I was following very closely. Some error pointed out was really syntax error, something lots of students confuse, and some comments addressed those problems, which is very good for knowledge sharing.

Now, where is the question? Was there some problem with it?

Comment: It's actually your question - there's no need to to be coy about the authorship. By giving the link any moderator (those with diamonds after their names) or any user with 10K or more reputation will be able to see it **and** the author.

Comment: Not intended to hide it. And yes, I assumed any privileged guy would know, so I simple forgot to mention. But thanks, I just edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was flagged as low-quality, and subsequently deleted by a moderator. I *suspect* (although I can't be sure) that it struck some readers as a bit too open-ended - you could probably fix this by re-wording it a bit (rather than "can you think of..." simply ask "what, besides an unclosed comment, constitutes a lexical error?")

I've undeleted it and made this adjustment.

Comment: Thanks Shog9. I'll keep that in mind when asking another question. But I'll say that it is too subtle for a non-native english speaker to see the difference in cases like this. Anyway, I'll try to be more objective (in a kind of rule-of- thumb).

Comment: It was a mistake; "low quality" isn't a reason for deletion.  At most, close as not a real question.  Never delete.

Comment: @Will I'm not sure why I'm getting only +5 for upvotes, and -1 for downvotes. Rep cap I don't think I have. Looking the best people in the rank I saw larsmans did 130 just today, 70 from a single post. Is there anything I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Forget about it @Will. This is the correct value for *questions*, not *answers*. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I believe that it was a moderation error.  Whoever the mod is that deleted the question should be fully ashamed of himself.  It was flagged as "low quality" by a user that flags just about everything as low quality.  The usual response to his flags is to dismiss as invalid.  I think the clickie must have come before the thinkie, as deleting *any* question outright (other than spam) is not an acceptable action.

Answer (score 1):

According to the 404 page:

> This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation.

[This indicates that a user other than the author of the question deleted the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71179/add-message-saying-question-was-deleted-instead-of-the-generic-page-not-found/85858#85858). Either a number of community users, or a moderator, deemed that there were enough problems with the post to warrant its deletion.

Comment: Thanks @Grace but that is so vague. The question had its value. Couldn't it at least be closed, and the answers at disposal of people who searches for that? Couldn't *me* at least read the answers once before it is deleted? Thanks.

Comment: @Dr Beco: It's been undeleted now. Before I had a chance to vote, another moderator saw your inquiry here and re-opened it. Thanks for following proper channels to discuss this!

Comment: @DrBeco Usually, that is the course of action. That's what closing is for, after all. I can't tell you the strict reason why it ended up specifically deleted (and, apparently, without closure first), since I wasn't involved in it.

Comment: @DrBeco Also, I wasn't aware that you were the author of the question - there are many requests on Meta Stack Overflow [on the subject of seeing own deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions "Closed as a duplicate of a status-declined, but I prefer this more recent discussion as a launch point"). It's currently declined, though, but it may change if there's good enough support provided.

Comment: If we can't see our mistakes, we can't learn. Thank you guys/gals :) for that.